# Плавное sticky menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста, есть вот такое меню 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/VrGvpK)
Как добиться плавности прилипания меню хотя бы как тут
 [hashiva](http://hashiva.s215.upress.link/)

```js
var num = 300; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
    $('.container').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.container').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="block regular"></div>
```

Comment: там в вопросе я прикрепил пример, что непонятного ?

Answer (score 1):

Задайте классу fixed свойство transition в css.
Например:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
```

Или, если по простому, то можно задать:

```
position: sticky;
```

Второй вариант работает без js.

Answer (score 1):

можно добавить просто  `transition: all .3s;`

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 700) {
    $('.container').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('.container').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

body {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: navy;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.block {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="block regular"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если кому-то нужен ответ на это в **19**м году, то вот.

Сделаем эффект "выезда" из верхней границы.

```js
let menuElem = $('.menu'), // Элемент который будет прилепать
    menuFixed = 300, // кол-во пикселей от границы, когда меню "прилипнет" к краю экрана.
    menuStatus = false; // Некая оптимизация.


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= menuFixed && menuStatus === false) {
    menuStatus = true;
    menuElem.addClass('--fixed').animate({'top':'0%'}, 500, 'linear');
  } else if($(this).scrollTop() < menuFixed && menuStatus === true) {
    menuStatus = false;
    menuElem.animate({'top':'-100%'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
      menuElem.removeAttr('style').removeClass('--fixed');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.menu.--fixed { /* .--fixed - это тот самый класс, который будет добавлятся, чтобы "прижать" меню */
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%; /* -100% для того, чтобы выезд сделать плавным. */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ----- -->
<div class="menu"></div>
```